# What makes libadalang special?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ada

I have been reading about libadalang [1](https://blog.adacore.com/introducing-libadalang) [2](https://blog.adacore.com/highlighting-ada-with-libadalang) and I am very impressed by it. However, I was wondering if this technique has already been used and another language supports a library for  syntactically and semantically analyzing its code. Is this a unique approach?

Answer (score 4):

C and C++: [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) "The C Interface to Clang provides a relatively small API that exposes facilities for parsing source code into an abstract syntax tree (AST), loading already-parsed ASTs, traversing the AST, associating physical source locations with elements within the AST, and other facilities that support Clang-based development tools." (See [libtooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) for a C++ API)

Python: See the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) module in the [Python Language Services](https://docs.python.org/3/library/language.html) section of the Python Library manual. (The other modules can be useful, as well.)

Javascript: The ongoing [ESTree](https://github.com/estree/estree) effort is attempting to standardize parsing services over different Javascript engines.

C# and Visual Basic: See the [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

I'm sure there are lots more; those ones just came off the top of my head.

For a practical and theoretical grounding, you should definitely (re)visit the classical textbook [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) by Abelson & Sussman (1st edition 1985, 2nd edition 1996), which helped popularise the idea of Metacircular Interpretation -- that is, interpreting a computer program as a formal datastructure which can be interpreted (or otherwise analysed) programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can see "libadalang" as ASIS Mark II.  AdaCore seems to be attempting to rethink ASIS in a way that will support both what ASIS already can do, and more lightweight operations, where you don't require the source to compile, to provide an analysis of it.

Hopefully the final API will be nicer than that of ASIS.

So no, it is not a unique approach.  It has already been done for Ada.  (But I'm not aware of similar libraries for other languages.)

Comment: So why is this tactic used by ASIS and libadalang unique to Ada? it seems like something that would be awesome for C++/Rust/etc.

Comment: I can see that it isn't unique to Ada.  The reason that Ada got it 19 years ago is probably that it is hard to parse Ada properly for an independent tool vendor.  ASIS allows the independent tool vendors to leverage the efforts made by the compiler vendors.